# Postgresql XML generation with special characters in column aliases

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a little problem with creating xml with double quoted column aliases. When converting to xml using double quotes I've got Unicode values on output (eg. _x0020 for space).

Executing this:

```
SELECT xmlforest('abc' AS "   ", 123 AS bar);
```

Gives me:

```
<_x0020__x0020__x0020_>abc</_x0020__x0020__x0020_><bar>123</bar>
```

How can I avoid xml Unicode values in output xml?

Comment: Do you actually need empty tag? maybe "123 as bar" is enough?

check the docs of xml-functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-xml.html

Also postgres has a good docs about string functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html 

did you use that?
"   ".convert_to("  ", 'UTF8')
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have space in tag: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-STag

Postgres is replacing     for you to have text processors properly consume such xml.

I assume you don't need spaces in tags, such example works perfectly ok:

```
# SELECT xmlforest('abc' AS "Tag", 123 AS bar);
          xmlforest           
------------------------------
 <Tag>abc</Tag><bar>123</bar>
```